# how to create a contents page containing speaker names and their titles for an abstracts book of a conference?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have been creating a latex template for an abstract book of our workshop. I have defined new commands such as `titleoftalk`, `speaker`, `speakeaddress`, `email`, ...

```
\newcommand{\titleoftalk}[1]{\begin{center}{\large \bf #1}\\\end{center}} 
\newcommand{\speaker}[1]{\begin{center}{\large #1}\end{center}}
\newcommand{\speakeraddress}[1]{\vspace{-0.75cm}\begin{center}{\it #1}\\ \vspace{1cm} ABSTRACT \end{center}}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\textit{email:} \url{#1}}
```

and wrote my abstracts for each speaker using these new commands. I need a help to write `\addtocontents{toc}` command.

Suppose we have 2 abstracts:

```
\speaker{Speaker 1}
\titleoftalk{Title 1}
%abstract of the first speaker is here
\speaker{Speaker 2}
\titleoftalk{Title 2}
%abstract of the second speaker is here
```

I want to recreate the toc page as

```
Title of Talks
1. Speaker 1   Title 1   ................................... the page number   
2. Speaker 2   Title 2   ................................... the page number
```

Where and how should I write my `\addtocontents{toc}`   command?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I noticed that you haven't accepted answers to your questions (nice questions, by the way!). I know that you have up-voted answers, but accepting them is a different action; in case of doubt please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: I updated my answer with another option.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{speaker}

\newcommand{\speaker}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{speaker}%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \begin{center}{\large #1}\end{center}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thespeaker.}#1}
}

\newcommand{\titleoftalk}[1]{%
  \begin{center}{\large\bfseries #1}\end{center}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.8em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\par%\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.8em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\contentsname{Title of Talks}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\speaker{Name of Speaker A}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker one}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker B}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker two}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker C}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker three}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker D}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker four}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker E}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker five}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to use the standard `\tableofcontents` command and `\addcontensline` inside `\speaker` and `\titleoftalk` so that the inclusion in the modified ToC will be automatic. Each speaker name will be formatted as a section and the corresponding title, as a subsection (using slightly modified versions of the default `\l@section` and `\l@subsection`). Provision was made so that if `hyperref` is used, anchors will be added in the appropriate locations to have functional hyperlinks.

Here's a variation putting the speaker name and the tile in the same line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{speaker}

\newcommand{\speaker}[1]{%
  \gdef\currspeaker{#1}
  \stepcounter{speaker}%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \begin{center}{\large #1}\end{center}
}
\newcommand{\titleoftalk}[1]{%
  \begin{center}{\large\bfseries #1}\end{center}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thespeaker.}\currspeaker~--~{\itshape#1}}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.8em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode %\bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.8em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\contentsname{Title of Talks}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\speaker{Name of Speaker A}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker one spanning more than one line for the example}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker B}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker two}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker C}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker three spanning more than one line for the example}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker D}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker four}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker E}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker five spanning more than one line for the example}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case one cannot (ab)use the standard `\tableofcontents` (because, for example, it has to be used for its intending purpose), one can easily modify the above examples and produce a `\listoftalks` command with the help of `\@starttoc`; here's an example showing this approach with the formatting used in the second example code above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{speaker}

\newcommand{\speaker}[1]{%
  \gdef\currspeaker{#1}
  \stepcounter{speaker}%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \begin{center}{\large #1}\end{center}
}
\newcommand{\titleoftalk}[1]{%
  \begin{center}{\large\bfseries #1}\end{center}
  \addcontentsline{tot}{speaker}{\numberline{\thespeaker.}\currspeaker~--~{\itshape#1}}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listtalksname{Title of Talks}
\newcommand\listoftalks{\section*{\listtalksname}\@starttoc{tot}}
\newcommand*\l@speaker[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.8em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode %\bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftalks
\newpage
\speaker{Name of Speaker A}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker one spanning more than one line for the example}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker B}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker two}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker C}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker three spanning more than one line for the example}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker D}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker four}
\lipsum[1-10]
\speaker{Name of Speaker E}
\titleoftalk{This is the title of the talk by speaker five spanning more than one line for the example}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]